# MySQL, Determine number of customer doing first transaction on certain store

Tags: mysql, sql

I have transaction table as below

```
OrderID | CustomerID | StoreID | Date   
1       |          C | Store2  | June 28
2       |          A | Store1  | June 30
3       |          A | Store1  | July 01
4       |          B | Store1  | July 10
5       |          C | Store1  | July 11
```

**"I want number of newly registred customer who did their first transaction on Store1 during July 01 - July 30"**

In this case the expected result is 1 which is CustomerID B with OrderID 4

How to query out the data with using EXISTS / NOT EXISTS, but not using IN / NOT IN?

This is what I got so far but I don't want to use NOT IN for solution

```
>     SELECT CustomerID
>     FROM table_transaction
>     WHERE StoreID = 'Store1'
>     AND OrderDate BETWEEN '2021-07-01' AND '2021-07-30'
>     AND CustomerID not IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM table_transaction WHERE OrderDate < '2021-07-01') GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Moreover since the date is parameterized, the where clause on date should be the same. Above solution the date parameter is not exactly the same, as first I'm using between and in subquery I'm using date less than the initial date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How do you do it with IN/NOT IN? And why is EXISTS/NOT EXISTS required here?

Comment: Can you please explain how the output is `B` ?

Comment: @JSBach due to performance issue we want solution using EXISTS/NOT EXISTS compared to IN/NOT IN

Comment: What to you mean by "number of customer"? If you mean how many customers were within the given date in Store1, and you restrict it to CustomerId B, it can be only 0 or 1, right?

Comment: Great, so show us the query with the poor performance

Comment: What is the type of your `Date` column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen type is DATETIME

Comment: "I want the number of customers whose first purchase was from Store1, and occurred between the 1st and 30th July"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach... with no IN or EXISTS...

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(OrderID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,CustomerID CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,StoreID INT NOT NULL
,Date DATE NOT NULL
,KEY(StoreID,Date)
,KEY(CustomerID,StoreID,Date)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'C',2,'2021-06-28'),
(2,'A',1,'2021-06-30'),
(3,'A',1,'2021-07-01'),
(4,'B',1,'2021-07-10'),
(5,'C',1,'2021-07-11');
```

...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT CustomerID, StoreID, MIN(Date) date FROM my_table GROUP BY CustomerID, StoreID ) b
    ON b.CustomerID = a.CustomerID 
   AND b.StoreID = a.StoreID
   AND b.Date = a.Date
 WHERE a.StoreID = 1
   AND a.Date BETWEEN '2021-07-01' AND '2021-07-30';
   
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|     2 |
+-------+
```

Edit: For the alternative (and incorrectly stated) interpretation of your problem, something like this should suffice:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) total
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT CustomerID, MIN(Date) date FROM my_table GROUP BY CustomerID) b
    ON b.CustomerID = a.CustomerID 
   AND b.Date = a.Date
 WHERE a.StoreID = 1
   AND a.Date BETWEEN '2021-07-01' AND '2021-07-30';
```

Comment: Result should be just 1 not 2, which is  CustomerID B with OrderID 4

Comment: I also think the result is 2, customer C's first record is in July for Store 1.

Comment: In which case your definition of your problem is misleading. Customer C's first purchase from Store1 was in July.

Comment: Thanks @JSBach I think your solution could be the answer. Let me take more time to observe this query against my production data and test it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.CustomerID) number_of_customers
FROM table_transaction t1
WHERE t1.StoreID = 'Store1' 
    AND t1.Date >= '2021-07-01' AND t1.Date < '2021-07-31'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM table_transaction t2 
      WHERE t2.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID AND t2.Date < '2021-07-01'
    )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c34ad1d3e6e872f82490fbacc41c814).
Result:

| number_of_customers |
| --- |
| 1 |

Answer (score 1):

> "I want number of newly registred customer who did their first transaction on Store1 during July 01 - July 30"

You can use aggregation with `having` to get the list of such customers:

```
select customerid
from transactions t
group by customerid
having min(date) >= '2021-07-01' and
       min(date) < '2021-07-31' and
       min(date) = min(case when store = 'store1' then date end);
```

If you want the count, you can aggregate twice:

```
select count(*)
from (select customerid
      from transactions t
      group by customerid
      having min(date) >= '2021-07-01' and
             min(date) < '2021-07-31' and
             min(date) = min(case when store = 'store1' then date end)
     ) c
```

Comment: This is a lot better in terms of query performance. Thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff

Comment: yes it is unique technique and better performance but I'm using 3rd party tools to do parameterized where clause and it cannot accept min(date) as a column parameter. So for now I'm using JSBach solution

Answer (score 0):

This can work, and with good indexes is also efficent:

```
SELECT      COUNT(table_transaction.CustomerID)
FROM        table_transaction
LEFT JOIN   table_transaction t2 ON
            t2.CustomerID = table_transaction.CustomerId AND
            t2.StoreID = 'Store1' AND
            t2.OrderDate < '2021-07-01'
WHERE       table_transaction.StoreID = 'Store1' AND
            table_transaction.OrderDate BETWEEN '2021-07-01' AND '2021-07-30' AND
            t2.OrderId IS NULL
```

This selects the **count** of customers, if you want a list, remove `COUNT` part of `SELECT`.

Note: as the previous answer suggests, the result is count 2, customers B and C also fit in, not as the question states.

Comment: I like this 'old school' approach, but just to note that it rarely outperforms a subquery.

Comment: At least we agree that the result is 2 :-)

Comment: Result should be just 1. CustomerID C first transaction is not within July

Comment: Yes, it is for Store1, because the first transaction of C was in Store2 in June. Your question explicitely says Store1 as condition.